# How can I make my CSS Grid layout responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid

I am having problems with the grid flow on my website. I want it to be responsive; the problem is that my page currently isn't responsive. any ideas?

```css
/*body  styles*/
body{background-color:#4B88A2;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size:16px;color: #FFF9FB;font-weight: 400;
 display: grid;
  grid: "header header"
        "nav nav"
        "content sidebar"
        "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 25%; }

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.content-wrap{max-width:950px; padding:50px;  margin:0 auto;overflow: auto;}
/*headers*/
h1 {font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;font-size:80px;color:#BB0A21;}
h4{font-size:20px;color:#252627;}
.box{;margin:0;overflow: auto;}
.container{margin: 40px auto 0;
width:90%;}

header { grid-area: header; }
nav { grid-area: nav; }
footer { grid-area: footer; }

.element {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-columns: 5em 3;
    -webkit-columns: 5em 3;
    columns: 5em 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 3px dashed orange;
    -moz-column-rule: 3px dashed orange;
    column-rule: 3px dashed orange;
    text-align: justify;}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
   grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 300px 175px; 
  grid-column-gap: 10px; 
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
/*navigation*/
nav{margin-bottom:5px;}
nav{text-align:left;position: fixed;top:0;left:0; width:100%;background:#D3D4D9;  }
nav a{display:inline-block;
 padding:15px 20px;
 text-decoration:none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight:bold;}
.nav-right{position:relative; top:0px; display:flex;}

/*box floats*/
#Next-skills-to-learn{display:inline-block;padding:10px;border: dotted 1px red;}
 /*footer*/
.footer{position:fixed;bottom:0;left: 0; width:100%;text-align: center;background:#252627;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <!-- Font styles-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/multiColumnTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/normalized.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="content-wrap">
  <!--navigation-->
  <nav class="nav" id="menu">
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="larry main.html">Home</a>
  <a href="portfolio.html">Work</a>
  <a href="#">Education</a>
  <div class="nav-right" id="social links" style="float: right"> 
   <i class="fab fa-instagram" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="font-size:30px;color:blue;"></i>
<i class="fas fa-envelope" style="font-size:30px;color:red;"></i>



    </div>
   </nav>
  

   
   
   <!-- navigationend-->   
   
   <!-- center alignigned pictures-->
<div class="grid-container">
   <div class="grid-item">
 <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="place holder">
    <h2>Drawings</h2>
 </div>
   
  <div class="grid-item">
 <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="place holder">
    <h2>Websites</h2>
 </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
 <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="place holder">
    <h2>Business cards</h2>
 </div>
 
    <div class="grid-item">
 <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="place holder">
    <h2>Drawings</h2>
 </div>
   
  <div class="grid-item">
 <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="place holder">
    <h2>Websites</h2>
 </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
 <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="place holder">
    <h2>Business cards</h2>
 </div>
   
   </div>
   
   
  <!--container end--> 
   <div class="footer">
  <p>&copy;Larry J designs </p>
</div>
 
   <!--stickyfooter-->
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In what respect to you want it to be responsive? Whats your end goal?

Comment: I was trying to make my page responsive.    That is all .

Comment: Brush up you css skills and then you can save some time using responsive frameworks like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/), etc.

Comment: Why did someone close vote this as a request for an off-site resource?

Comment: I think we are going to need a bit more information than just "responsiveness." - What layout are you going for and how do you want it to be adjusted when the viewport changes? From your initial code, it looks like you want everything to be centered and have your images in a central 3-column layout. It also looks like you are setting a `grid` for your `body` and a `grid` for your `content` that are essentially doing the same thing. You are also using `grid-area` but it doesn't seem to be clearly defined. It may help to add pictures of what you are looking to achieve

Comment: So how do i do this   ?  I want to center align the grid .   I should play   grids though .I want to have a portfolio page.  Some one suggested  boot strap i  agree but thats hell . lls.

Comment: I fixed that thank you . I did see that !!